# How not to lose properties that are present in my destination object but are NOT in my source object after mapping using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a following class structure:

```
public class A
{
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
    public bool Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerForA
{
    public A A { get; set; }
}

public class A1
{
    public bool Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerForA1
{
    public A1 A { get; set; }
}
```

I create a mapping for this set of classes:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A1, A>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ContainerForA1, ContainerForA>();
```

I create an instance of this set of classes:

```
        var cnt_a = new ContainerForA()
                        {
                            A = new A()
                                    {
                                        Property1 = false,
                                        Property2 = true
                                    }
                        };

        var cnt_a1 = new ContainerForA1()
                         {
                             A = new A1()
                                     {
                                         Property1 = true
                                     }
                         };
```

If I call `Mapper.Map(cnt_a1.A, cnt_a.A)` I'm getting the result I was expecting: both properties (`Property1` and `Property2`) of object **cnt_a** are **true**

But if I call `Mapper.Map(cnt_a1, cnt_a)` I'm getting true for `Property1` and false for `Property2`. Could someone explain me why? And is there any option for me to declare my mappings in the way so I won't lose properties that are present in my destination object but are NOT in my source object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that when you map from `ContainerForA1` to `ContainerForA`, that when mapping the property A, it creates a new instance of `A` for `ContainerForA` rather than using the existing one.   This will use the default values for all of the properties, which is `false` for a `bool`.

How do we work around this?

First, we need to tell AutoMapper to not overwrite the property A on ContainerForA.  To do that, we will tell AutoMapper to ignore the property.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContainerForA1, ContainerForA>()
    .ForMember(cForA => cForA.A, option => option.Ignore());
```

Now we need to update A manually, using AfterMap

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContainerForA1, ContainerForA>()
    .ForMember(cForA => cForA.A, option => option.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((cForA1, cForA) => Mapper.Map(cForA1.A, cForA.A));
```

You will probably want to add some checks to the AfterMap method to ensure that cForA.A is not null.  I'll leave that for you.

Comment: In this case, why don't we lose all properties when we map cnt_a1.A to cnt_a.A? I would suggest to have false for Property2 since it should be instantiated with the default value as well..

Comment: When you map cnt_a1.A to cnt_a.A, you already have an instance of each object and it is mapping the properties.  If you were to do something like `A a = Mapper.Map<A1, A>(cnt_a1.a);` you will see that a.Property2 is false because it is creating a new A.

Comment: I just noticed a bug in my sample code in the AfterMap lambda expression and I have corrected it.

Comment: What do you mean under 'you already have an instance of each object'? It seens like I have equal objects during Mapper.Map(cnt_a1, cnt_a)/Mapper.Map(cnt_a1.A, cnt_a.A). The only difference is in the object I apply mapping to..