# Automapper instantiates destination object instead of mapping recursively

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map my DTO object to entity object in my factory class. DTO has all field values straight, whereas entity has fields which consist of Name and Value.

After some debugging, I found Automapper instantiates each entity fields instead of using existing one. As a result, the last test fails.

```
[TestFixture]
class RecursiveMappingTest
{
    public class SourceInfo
    {
        public string Info1 = "info1";
        public string Info2 = "info1";
    }

    public class StringField
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Value;
    }

    public class DestinationInfo
    {
        public StringField Info1 = new StringField() { Name = "field name 1" };
        public StringField Info2 = new StringField() { Name = "field name 2" };
    }

    [Test]
    public void MapField()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<string, StringField>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

        Mapper.CreateMap<SourceInfo, DestinationInfo>();

        SourceInfo sourceInfo = new SourceInfo();
        DestinationInfo destinationInfo = new DestinationInfo();

        Mapper.Map(sourceInfo, destinationInfo);

        // these pass
        Assert.That(destinationInfo.Info1.Value, Is.EqualTo("info1"));
        Assert.That(destinationInfo.Info2.Value, Is.EqualTo("info1"));

        // this fails since automapper instantiated brand new StringField()
        // which has Name == "".
        Assert.That(destinationInfo.Info1.Name, Is.EqualTo("field name 1"));
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior? How can I achieve what I want? There are tons of fields in the entity classes so [this workaround will not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346571/how-not-to-lose-properties-that-are-present-in-my-destination-object-but-are-not).

Comment: I ended up using [ValueInjector](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to solve this problem. It also solved other Automapper challenges I had to go through once this problem gets solved. ValueInjector doesn't have any magic but everything is transparent - or should I say the simple structure is truly the magic - and source code is easy to grasp and learn from to make your customized injection code. I will leave this question open since I am curious to know this particular problem in Automapper.

Comment: If the number of fields in the entity is the problem you could always use a t4 template.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your second map to:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceInfo, DestinationInfo>()
.ForAllMembers(x => x.UseDestinationValue());
```

This should use destination values for all un-mapped attributes.

Comment: Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() fails but it works for me since I have different way to check if everything is mapped well. Thanks Void Ray!

Comment: I found another issue. Weird, but if I change the value to be the same (like both to be `"info1"`) I get an error saying `System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.` I changed the question to reflect the problem.